# What is wrong with my Radare2 Visual mode?

Tags: radare2

When I open a file in radare2 and then enter `Vpp`, the first line appears next to the registers. Is this a bug or a config parameter which I could change ? 
That problem persists even if I move in the file with `j` or `k`

And if it's a bug, is there a 'context' parameter so that I can print 1 line above the line where I have the focus ? (by focus, I dont mean the address where I seek but the address where I put a comment pressing `;`)

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIaDg.png)

Thanks

Comment: Hello Saperlu, can you provide what version of radare2 you are using? You can check the version of radare2 by using the command: user@host:~$ r2 -v .  If you are using a version of radare2 older than 4.4.0 I recommend cloning the official git repository, https://github.com/radareorg/radare2, and following the installation instructions found here: https://github.com/radareorg/radare2#install--update